# Good basemap generator

Tags: maps

I am currently making a board game and cannot seem to find any vector world map creators where I can select a region of the world to capture and have it download that section. I just want a base map so no city names and preferably no borders.

The map doesn't have to be vector if it is of good enough quality.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded high resolution JPG maps for some clients with the [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) tool. Its a software you need to install on your computer but it gives access to Google-style maps with tons of [customization](https://www.mapbox.com/help/style-quickstart/) options and everything you do can be exported as 300dpi JPG files. Not vector but in good (print) quality.

You can remove city names, borders and everything you want via a CSS-style language they are using and there are also some ready-made styles you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Wikimedia Commons has [various blank SVG maps of the world](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Blank_SVG_maps_of_the_world).

The useful thing about SVG is that you already have the polygon information about the borders in an easily parseable XML format. Most of these maps even have the country-paths named with the ISO country-codes. When you are developing a web application, you can even make that map interactive with some JavaScript.

If you want only a part of the map, you will need to cut them out with a vector graphics editor like Inkscape.

But if you want to use one of these maps, keep the license conditions in mind. Most of them are in the public domain, which means you can use them freely. Others are under share-alike licenses which can make it hard to monetize your game if you use them.